# Drop Down Menu in swift error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently attempting to re-work this navigation dropdown menu

https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu

When I tried it, I'm getting an error

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value ( in the below line.)

```
var frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, titleSize.width + (self.configuration.arrowPadding + self.configuration.arrowImage.size.width)*2, self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height)
```

I don't know how to make changes in storyboard for this set of code. I'm working on Xcode 7 beta 4 in swift.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is similar to the question asked yesterday  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114651/attempting-to-get-reference-to-container-view-controller, I tried to copy the images too as said in the solution, even after that I'm getting the error. I don't know how to make changes in storyboard @jvolen2

Comment: @Sunny Shah I didn't get the changes u edited, all I find is the same code

Comment: When I use the Entry point in Navigation Controller, it works, but I'm using a Menu option of sidebar type. that doesn't work when I set the entry point to navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i fixed it 
In your view Controller

```
 let menuView = BTNavigationDropdownMenu(title: "Sort By", items: items,navigation: self.navigationController!)
```

Then change in BTNavigationDropdownMenu class

```
 public init(title: String, items: [AnyObject])
```

To

```
public init(title: String, items: [AnyObject], navigation : UINavigationController)
```

And for navigationController variable change to

```
self.navigationController = navigation
```